# Error message when adding a new data (transaction aborded)

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

am using jsf 2.0 + primefaces 3.2 + EJB 2.0 + JPA 2.0 .
hi everyone, when i try to affect a new student to a class the system raises an error message which is trasaction abored. 
my entity code : ClasseHasEtudiant

```
public class ClasseHasEtudiant implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@EmbeddedId
protected ClasseHasEtudiantPK classeHasEtudiantPK;
@JoinColumn(name = "Etudiant_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Etudiant etudiant;
@JoinColumn(name = "Classe_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Classe classe;

public ClasseHasEtudiant() {
}

public ClasseHasEtudiant(ClasseHasEtudiantPK classeHasEtudiantPK) {
    this.classeHasEtudiantPK = classeHasEtudiantPK;
}

public ClasseHasEtudiant(int classeid, int etudiantid) {
    this.classeHasEtudiantPK = new ClasseHasEtudiantPK(classeid, etudiantid);
}

public ClasseHasEtudiantPK getClasseHasEtudiantPK() {
    return classeHasEtudiantPK;
}

public void setClasseHasEtudiantPK(ClasseHasEtudiantPK classeHasEtudiantPK) {
    this.classeHasEtudiantPK = classeHasEtudiantPK;
}

public Etudiant getEtudiant() {
    return etudiant;
}

public void setEtudiant(Etudiant etudiant) {
    this.etudiant = etudiant;
}

public Classe getClasse() {
    return classe;
}

public void setClasse(Classe classe) {
    this.classe = classe;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (classeHasEtudiantPK != null ? classeHasEtudiantPK.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof ClasseHasEtudiant)) {
        return false;
    }
    ClasseHasEtudiant other = (ClasseHasEtudiant) object;
    if ((this.classeHasEtudiantPK == null && other.classeHasEtudiantPK != null) || (this.classeHasEtudiantPK != null && !this.classeHasEtudiantPK.equals(other.classeHasEtudiantPK))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "dossierEtudiants.entities.ClasseHasEtudiant[ classeHasEtudiantPK=" + classeHasEtudiantPK + " ]";
}
```

}

code of entity ClasseHasEtudiantPK

```
@Embeddable
public class ClasseHasEtudiantPK implements Serializable {
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "Classe_id")
private int classeid;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "Etudiant_id")
private int etudiantid;

public ClasseHasEtudiantPK() {
}

public ClasseHasEtudiantPK(int classeid, int etudiantid) {
    this.classeid = classeid;
    this.etudiantid = etudiantid;
}

public int getClasseid() {
    return classeid;
}

public void setClasseid(int classeid) {
    this.classeid = classeid;
}

public int getEtudiantid() {
    return etudiantid;
}

public void setEtudiantid(int etudiantid) {
    this.etudiantid = etudiantid;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (int) classeid;
    hash += (int) etudiantid;
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof ClasseHasEtudiantPK)) {
        return false;
    }
    ClasseHasEtudiantPK other = (ClasseHasEtudiantPK) object;
    if (this.classeid != other.classeid) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.etudiantid != other.etudiantid) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "dossierEtudiants.entities.ClasseHasEtudiantPK[ classeid=" + classeid + ", etudiantid=" + etudiantid + " ]";
}
```

}

this is my .xhtml code :

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
            <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantLabel_etudiant}" for="etudiant" />
                <h:selectOneMenu id="etudiant" value="#{classeHasEtudiantController.selected.etudiant}" title="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantTitle_etudiant}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantRequiredMessage_etudiant}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{etudiantController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantLabel_classe}" for="classe" />
                <h:selectOneMenu id="classe" value="#{classeHasEtudiantController.selected.classe}" title="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantTitle_classe}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantRequiredMessage_classe}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{classeController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <h:commandLink action="#{classeHasEtudiantController.create}" value="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantSaveLink}" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:commandLink action="#{classeHasEtudiantController.prepareList}" value="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantShowAllLink}" immediate="true"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h:commandLink value="#{bundle.CreateClasseHasEtudiantIndexLink}" action="/index" immediate="true" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

and this is my managedBean code :

```
    public String prepareCreate() {
    current = new ClasseHasEtudiant();
    current.setClasseHasEtudiantPK(new dossierEtudiants.entities.ClasseHasEtudiantPK());
    selectedItemIndex = -1;
    return "Create";
}

public String create() {
    try {
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle1").getString("ClasseHasEtudiantCreated"));
        return prepareCreate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle1").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

and finaly my log :

```
    Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`isetdb`.`classe_has_etudiant`, CONSTRAINT `classe_has_etudiant_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Classe_id`) REFERENCES `classe` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
Error Code: 1452
Call: INSERT INTO classe_has_etudiant (Classe_id, Etudiant_id) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(entities.ClasseHasEtudiant[ classeHasEtudiantPK=entities.ClasseHasEtudiantPK[ classeid=0, etudiantid=0 ] ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1702)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2863)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3784)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:852)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5114)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4879)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy302.create(Unknown Source)
    at sessionBeans.__EJB31_Generated__ClasseHasEtudiantFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at managedBeans.ClasseHasEtudiantController.create(ClasseHasEtudiantController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`isetdb`.`classe_has_etudiant`, CONSTRAINT `classe_has_etudiant_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Classe_id`) REFERENCES `classe` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2327)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2312)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:831)
    ... 87 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database schema suggest that `Classe_id` is a foreign key.

But while saving class you are assigning a new Primary key which basically sets `classeid` and `etudiantid` to zero, and while saving record there are no records with matching id.

Current Implementation:

```
current.setClasseHasEtudiantPK(new dossierEtudiants.entities.ClasseHasEtudiantPK());
```

Instead you should set the id of Class and id of Student between which you are doing the mapping.

Looking from the xhtml I think in your managed bean you would be having something like

`selected.classe` which holds the selected class and `selected.etudiant` which holds the selected, so your code should look something like this:

```
ClasseHasEtudiantPK classeHasEtudiantPK = new dossierEtudiants.entities.ClasseHasEtudiantPK(selected.classe.classeid, selected.etudiant.etudiantid);
//Note depending upon your code the above two values selected.classe.classeid and selected.etudiant.etudinatid may change, so set according to your code.
current.setClasseHasEtudiantPK(classeHasEtudiantPK);
```